# How to save state of page even after reloading or closing the browser?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a quiz application using laravel as backend and vuejs to render the questions on the frontend. The thing that is confusing me how to store the state of quiz even after candidate reloads the page or he/she accidentally close the browser. I am thinking about saving the quiz progress in the database. Is there any better approach than this?

```
<template>

    <div>

    <div class="container quiz-steps" v-for="(question,index) in questions" v-bind:key="index">
        <div v-show="index === currentIndex && timer>0">
        <div>
            <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ minutes }}</span>
            <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ seconds }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" :style="{width: returnTimerWidth()}" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container-quiz-question-pills">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills quiz-question-pills">
                <li><a href="#"> {{ wrong }}</a><i class="icon-remove"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#"> {{ right }} </a><i class="icon-ok"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="question-content">
            <p>{{ question.question }}</p>
            <!-- Material unchecked -->
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" v-model="picked" class="form-check-input" value="1" id="radio1" name="materialExampleRadios">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">{{ question.option1 }}</label>
            </div>

            <!-- Material checked -->
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" v-model="picked" class="form-check-input" value="2" id="radio2" name="materialExampleRadios">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">{{ question.option2 }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" v-model="picked" class="form-check-input" value="3" id="radio3" name="materialExampleRadios">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio3">{{ question.option3 }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="radio" v-model="picked" class="form-check-input" value="3" id="radio4" name="materialExampleRadios">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio4">{{ question.option4 }}</label>
            </div>
    enter code here
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div>
            <span> {{index+1}} / {{questions.length}} </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger float-right btn-next" @click="nextQuestion(question.isCorrect)">Next</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" :style="{width: returnWidth(index)}" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin=0 aria-valuemax="100"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <div v-if="currentIndex === questions.length || timer==0">
            <div class="container thankyou-quiz-page">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <p>Thnakyou for taking the Quiz!</p>
                    <br>
                    <div class="thankyou-msg">
                        <p>You have answered <span>{{ right }}</span> correct answers out of <span>{{ questions.length }}</span>. Your total time was <span>{{ minutesTaken }}:{{ secondsTaken }}</span>. The answers were sent to the administrator and he will contact you shortly.</p>
                        <p>Your total marks are {{ calculateScore() }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="text-center quiz-choice">
                        <a href="#" class="text-dark">Retake the Quiz</a><br>
                        <a href="#" class="text-dark">Next Quiz</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="thankyou-message-button">
                    <a href="Quiz--question-page.html"><button type="button" class="btn ">Retake the Quiz</button> </a>
                    <a href="Quiz--question-page.html"><button type="button" class="btn float-right ">Next Quiz</button> </a>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>

</template>


<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name:'TEST',
        props:['quizId'],
        data(){
            return{
                currentIndex:0,
                picked:'',
                right:0,
                wrong:0,
                questions:[

                ],
                timer:0,
                total:0,
                minutes:0,
                seconds:0,
                minutesTaken:0,
                secondsTaken:0,
                remainingTime:0,
                done:false,
                interval: '',
                negative: 0,
                totalMarks: 0,
                type: 0
            }
        },
        methods:{
           nextQuestion:function(e){
               if(this.picked){

                   if(e==this.picked){
                       this.right++;
                   }
                   else{
                       this.wrong++;
                   }

               }

               this.currentIndex++;

               if(this.currentIndex == this.questions.length){
                   this.timer = 0;
               }
               this.picked = '';


            },
            returnWidth(e){
               if( e==0 ){
                   return 0+'%';
               }
               else {
                   return e / this.questions.length * 100+'%';

               }




            },
            returnTimerWidth(){
               if( this.remainingTime == 0 )
               {
                   return 0+'%';
               }
               else{
                   return this.remainingTime / this.total * 100 + '%';

               }

                                },
            loadQuestions(){
                axios.get("http://192.168.1.3:8000/api/quiz/"+this.quizId).
                then( ({ data }) => ( this.questions = data.data.questions,
                       this.timer = data.data.timeAllowed * 60,
                       this.total = this.timer,
                        this.negative = data.data.negativePercentage,
                        this.getTime(this)


                ) )
            },
            getTime(){


                    let interval = setInterval( () => {
                    this.minutes = parseInt(this.timer / 60, 10);
                    this.seconds = parseInt(this.timer % 60, 10);
                    this.minutes = this.minutes < 10 ? "0" + this.minutes : this.minutes;
                    this.seconds = this.seconds < 10 ? "0" + this.seconds : this.seconds;

                    if (--this.timer <0 ) {
                        // this.timer = 0;
                        this.totalTime();
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                    else{
                        this.remainingTime++;
                        this.returnTimerWidth();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            },
            totalTime(){

                this.minutesTaken = parseInt(this.remainingTime / 60, 10);
                this.secondsTaken = parseInt(this.remainingTime % 60, 10);
                this.minutesTaken = this.minutesTaken < 10 ? "0" + this.minutesTaken : this.minutesTaken;
                this.secondsTaken = this.secondsTaken < 10 ? "0" + this.secondsTaken : this.secondsTaken;

            },
            calculateScore(){

               this.totalMarks = this.right - ( this.wrong * this.negative );


                // if(this.type==1){
                //     axios.post('http://192.168.1.3:8000/api/quizMarks', {
                //         Marks: this.totalMarks
                //     })
                //         .then(function (response) {
                //             console.log(response);
                //         })
                //         .catch(function () {
                //             // console.log(error);
                //         });
                //
                // }
                // else if(this.type==0){
                //     axios.post('http://192.168.1.3:8000/api/quizMarks', {
                //         Marks: this.totalMarks
                //     })
                //         .then(function (response) {
                //             console.log(response);
                //         })
                //         .catch(function () {
                //             // console.log(error);
                //         });
                // }

               return this.totalMarks;
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadQuestions();

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you hold the state of the quiz, on component state or vuex?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use local storage and check if the key exists once the page is loaded.

A cleaner way is to use vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/ and a local storage plugin such as vuex persist.

Comment: I have added code. I am basically rendering through the list and when user clicks for next question I look if the selected option was correct or not.

Comment: You can alternatively store state inside Cookies, but LocalStorage is much better way as Michael mentioned